# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX on "./src/App.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

I didn't write a single line of code, just generated via npm. When I want to run "npm start" I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq81K.png)

Here is the autogenerate code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to compile the site using create-react-app. It is my first react app

Comment: You must import react at top of the file: `import { React } from 'react'`

Comment: Seems like you’re using an earlier version of React where importing is still required.

Answer (score 0):

**Import the React Library**

To fix the error message, you need to import the React library at the beginning of the file.

Example of how to import the React library

```
import React from 'react';
```

**Important** to note that you need to make sure that the correct version of React is being imported. If you import an outdated or incorrect version of React, it can cause an error.